# Subsetting by various observations

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, subset

I have a data.frame that produces the following image:

```
ggplot(mouse_list, aes(x = Sex, y = Age, color = Mouseline)) +
  geom_beeswarm(cex = 3.2,
                size = 2)
```

[All Mouselines by Age and Sex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP5ZR.png)

I am looking for a method that would allow me to visualize any two Mouselines by sex and age, to produce something like the following:

[Desired data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DshW.png)

I produced the desired image by modifying the original .csv to include only the desired mouselines, then imported as a new data set, but I'd like to work with the single .csv that contains all the data.

Here is my str(mouse_list):

```
> str(mouse_list)
'data.frame':   745 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ **Sex**          : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Physical.Tag : chr  "M-1" "M269A-1" "M269A-2" "M269A-3" ...
 $ **Mouseline**    : chr  "_-ActinCre; MitoTag" "_-ActinCre; MitoTag" "_-ActinCre; MitoTag" "_-ActinCre; MitoTag" ...
 $ Genotype     : chr  "Cre(+)" "" "" "" ...
 $ Cage.Tag     : chr  "" "M269A" "M269A" "M269A" ...
 $ Mating.Tag   : chr  "M269" "" "" "" ...
 $ Date.of.Birth: chr  "2/24/20" "5/10/20" "5/10/20" "5/10/20" ...
 $ **Age**          : int  14 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 17 ...
 $ Status       : chr  "" "Awaiting GT" "Awaiting GT" "Awaiting GT" ...
 $ Notice       : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
```

I have tried the following (with errors provided):

```
ggplot(mouse_list$Mouseline=="KLBT" & "Fgf21 KO / KLBT KI", aes(x = Sex, y = Age, color = Mouseline)) +
+   geom_beeswarm(cex = 3.2,
+                 size = 2) 
Error in mouse_list$Mouseline == "KLBT" & "Fgf21 KO / KLBT KI" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

and:

```
    ggplot(mouse_list$Mouseline=="KLBT" & mouse_list$Mouseline=="Fgf21 KO / KLBT KI", aes(x = Sex, y = Age, color = Mouseline)) +
    +   geom_beeswarm(cex = 3.2,
    +                 size = 2) 
    Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a logical vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Running last_trace() produced:

```
rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a logical vector
Backtrace:
    █
 1. ├─ggplot2::ggplot(...)
 2. └─ggplot2:::ggplot.default(...)
 3.   ├─ggplot2::fortify(data, ...)
 4.   └─ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
```

Which is as clear as cultured plasmid broth...

I'm a novice, and I'd like to be able to present a better visualization for cohort determination to the group using one .csv file. I am happy to provide any other info needed.

Comment: Replace `mouse_list$Mouseline=="KLBT" & mouse_list$Mouseline=="Fgf21 KO / KLBT KI"` with `subset(mouse_list, Mouseline == "KLBT" | Mouseline == "Fgf21 KO / KLBT KI")`.

Comment: Ahhh... the OR operator. You're the guvner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider running all possible two-pair combinations of *Mouseline* using **`expand.grid`** and running plots with **`Map`**:

```
# DATA FRAME OF PAIR COMBINATIONS (AVOIDING DUPS AND REVERSE DUPS)
pairs_df <- subset(expand.grid(m1 = unique(mouse_list$Mouseline),
                               m2 = unique(mouse_list$Mouseline),
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                   m1 < m2)

# DEFINED METHOD TO FILTER DATA FRAME BY PAIRS AND PLOT
proc_plot <- function(m1, m2) {
    plot_df <- subset(mouselist, Mouseline == m1 | Mouseline == m2)

    ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = Sex, y = Age, color = Mouseline)) +
           geom_beeswarm(cex = 3.2, size = 2)

}

# BUILD LIST OF PLOTS
plot_list <- Map(proc_plot, pairs_df$m1, pairs_df$m2)

plot_list[[1]]
plot_list[[2]]
plot_list[[3]]
...
```

Comment: So, pairs_df produces 930 possible pairings. Which can be useful for me using my original script.  I'm very unsure of how to utilize the function part of your script to output the pairing plot I'm looking for.